# Right place to do class imbalance regularisation (data level or batch level)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have two binary imbalanced dataset where the labels are ether 0 or 1 and prediction output is between 0 and 1. The positive case has 10000 samples, while the negative case has 90000 samples. I'm using a batch of 100 when training.

when calculating the BinaryCrossEntropyLoss (in pytorch) its possible to supply the per batch element regularisation weight.

My question is:
To calculate the general class weight dose it make more sense to calculate it 1 time at the start (so 1/(10000/(100000) for the positive case) and scale the loss of each sample with this value

or:

Calculate the weight at the batch level, by firstly finding the batch class imbalance (e.g in the batch it might be 25 positives and 75 negatives, hence 1/(25/(25+75) for the positive case)

I'm asking this because the loss is averaged across the batch

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do it this way, you should calculate per batch class imbalance.

On the other hand you should probably make sure that each batch preserves label statistics (e.g. for batch `64` and your case, you should have `6` positive samples and the rest negative). This way, it would be enough to calculate class imbalance once and add it to [torch.nn.BCELoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BCELoss) on a per-batch basis.

I would suggest the other approach though, e.g. oversampling or undersampling using PyTorch's `Sampler` class (don't do it by copying examples, it wastes space totally unnecessarily). You can implement it manually or use third party library which did it for you for example [torchdata](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/torchdata) (disclosure: I'm the author) and [`torchdata.samplers.RandomOverSampler`](https://szymonmaszke.github.io/torchdata/packages/torchdata.samplers.html#torchdata.samplers.RandomOverSampler).